# Application and interpretation of $\delta$ Chernoff bound

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, expected-value

I came across Chernoff bound and experienced some difficulties in trying to interpret and apply it.

Let's revisit the Chebyshev inequality:

$$P\left(|X - E[X]| > \alpha \right) \leq \frac{\mathrm{Var}[X]}{\alpha^{2}}$$

is interpreted as the probability for which the distance between the outcome of a random variable $X$ and its expected value $E[X]$ being greater than some non-negative value $\alpha$ can be described by $\frac{\mathrm{Var}[X]}{\alpha^{2}} \in [0, 1]$.

It provides an upper bound to the probability that $|X - E[X]| > \alpha$ may occur.

The Chernoeff lower bound says this:

$$P\left(X < \left(1 - \delta\right)E[X]\right) < e^{-\frac{E[X]\delta^{2}}{2}}, \forall \delta \in [0, 1]~.$$

The Chernoff upper bound says this:

$$P\left(X > \left(1 + \delta\right)E[X]\right) < e^{-\frac{E[X]\delta^{2}}{4}}, \forall \delta \in [0, 2e - 1]~.$$

Now, I am considering the case of an unbias coin - outcomes being head or tails represented by 1 and 0 respectively - being flipped 100 times. I'd like to know the probability that more than 90 tails are obtained.

The struggle is with relating $\delta$, its range $[0, 1]$ for the lower bound and $[0, 2e-1]$ for the upper bound to the 100 coin flips.

Any help to better my understanding is appreciated.

**Note:** e is the base of the natural log

Comment: Here is one way to compare the guarantees: $\alpha$ in Chebyshev corresponds to $\delta \mathbb{E}[X]$ in your satement of the Chernoff bounds. So for you, $\mathbb{E}[X] = 50$, $\alpha=40$, $\delta=4/5$.

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you for the insight. 

But what does $\delta E[X]$ really mean from a physical reasoning point of view?

Comment: The same thing, but phrased differently -- as you wrote it, Chebyshev gives a bound for *additive* deviations from the mean, while Chernoff gives bounds for *relative* deviations. (So, "increase by $10" vs."increase by 5%.")

Comment: @ClementC.

as a check:

$P[X < E[X] - E[X].\delta] = 0.960$. Is this sane?

Comment: This is way too high here. The bound should be $$e^{-\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[X]\delta^2} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}\cdot 50\cdot \frac{4^2}{5^2}}  = e^{-16}$$
Another way to think about it is that, for $\alpha = \delta\mathbb{E}[X]$, the Chernoff bound gives 
$$
\Pr[X < \mathbb{E}[X]-\alpha] \leq e^{-\frac{\alpha^2}{2\mathbb{E}[X]}}
$$

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you - I think my output were odd. Turns out I missed a constant in my programmatic function.

Thank you for helping me to understanding

Comment: No worries at all!